# How to make bar charts for muultiple groups?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

Have a dataframe of multiple groups of stats of two classes, ex:

```
player   position   Points     target_class
lebron    sf          23             1
Magic     pg          22             0
```

How do I make bar charts of the average points per position(5 of them) but split for each class. So side by side plots in pandas.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it's hard to know what you are expecting. Using [`sns.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) like so should get you close to what I think you want.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

ax = sns.barplot(
    data=df,
    x="position",
    y="Points",
    hue="target_class",
    estimator=np.mean,
)
```